# shell Script to call another script with sleep parameter

Tags: shell

Request your help in the following. I have a requirement to call various shell script every 60 seconds/5 mins/10 mins. Basically, I need to create a master wrapper script which will call various scripts with appropriate time interval.

For example, Script A is the master wrapper which calls scripts B, C, D, E etc every 1, 5, 10, 15 mins. Script A should have two parameters (script name and sleep time) and should be able to call the script passed as parameter with the sleep time mentioned in the parameter as well.

Comment: Why not using crontab to achieve this ? http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab

Answer (score 0):

So, A is looping forever, and inside the loop, it calls the other script **in the background**, then sleeps, starts a new background process, etc.? If this really is all you are looking for (writing a loop, sleeping, invoking another script), maybe you can explain, where exactly you have a problem.

Maybe you can also show us what you already have implemented. It will make it easier to discuss the issue.

UPDATE:

Seeing the sketch of your script:

You must decide first, how you want to pass the parameters to your script. The more common way is to use positional parameters. Another possibility is to use environment variables.

In the former case, you would use $1 and $2 to access the first and the second parameter. Your script would be then called like this:

```
your_script ProgramToBeExecuted 5
```

In the latter case, you would have to decide on the name of the environment variables - say, NAME and SLEEP, as in your example -, but you have to access the content of the variables by $NAME, not NAME. "NAME" by itself is just a string. Your script - assuming that you use ksh (as your example suggests) - would then be invoked like this

```
NAME=ProgramToBeExecuted SLEEP=5 your_script
```

Comment: Sorry, you are right. This definitely should have been a comment. I will take care about it next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script

```
while [ 1 ]; do
ksh -x NAME
sleep SLEEP TIME
done
```

and passing script name and sleep time as parameter. So basically this script will call another script and sleep and call again.